# Dropdown Tailwind CSS menu with weird beviour

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am planning to use Tailwind CSS to build a navigation bar with a drop down menu in my app.

Unfortunately, I have an issue when I open the drop down. It pushes down the main content and the footer (please see the images attached).

**Not open:**

[image]

**Open:**

[image]

I copied the drop down code from Tailwind website, the main content (with the texts 'Dashboard') is just <div> elements.

#### File *Layout.js*

```
const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Outlet />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### File *Navbar.js*

```
const NavBar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className='bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700'>
            <div className='max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4'>
                <Logo />
                <OpenMenuForMobile />
                <Menu />
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

#### File *Menu.js*

```
const Menu = () => {
    return (
        <div
            className='hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto'
            id='navbar-dropdown'>
            <ul className='flex flex-col font-medium p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:flex-row md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700'>
                <MenuDropDown title='Administration' />
                <MenuSimpleItem title='Dashboard' path='#' />
                <MenuSimpleItem title='Stat' path='#' />
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### File *MenuDropDown.js*

```
const MenuDropDown = ( { title } ) => {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const handleMenuDropDown = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    }

    return (
        <li>
        <button
            id='dropdownNavbarLink'
            onClick={handleMenuDropDown}
            className='flex items-center justify-between w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:w-auto dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:focus:text-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent'>
            {title}
            <svg
                className='w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-2.5'
                aria-hidden='true'
                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                fill='none'
                viewBox='0 0 10 6'>
                <path
                    stroke='currentColor'
                    strokeLinecap='round'
                    strokeLinejoin='round'
                    strokeWidth='2'
                    d='m1 1 4 4 4-4' />
            </svg>
        </button>
        <div
            id='dropdownNavbar'
            className={`z-10 font-normal bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600 ${isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}>
            <ul
                className='py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400'
                aria-labelledby='dropdownLargeButton'>
                <MenuDropDownItem title='Programming languages' path='#' />
                <MenuDropDownItem title='Repositories' path='#' />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

    )
}
```

#### File *MenuDropDownItem.js*

```
const MenuDropDownItem = ({ title, path }) => {
    return (
        <li>
            <a
                href={path}
                className='block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white'>
                {title}
            </a>
        </li>
    )
}
```

#### File *Dashboard.js*

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        <div>Dashboard</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Why cannot the dropdown menu overlap the Dashboard content?

Comment: off hand i see there is nothing making the drop down render outside the regular flow css issue. where did you copy it from? if you want to provide a codesandbox with minimam reproducible code id be happy to try to help fix it

Comment: I think you should add `position: 'absolute'` css to `dropdownNavbar` div element.

Comment: Just a tip, something I learned from experience. Keep your browser up to date, this helps avoid unexpected issues during development, not saying it will fix your issue at all but it won't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my updated `MenuDropDown.js`. My way is to add CSS `position: 'absolute'` in the dropdown menu.

```html
<li className="relative">
    <button
        id='dropdownNavbarLink'
        onClick={handleMenuDropDown}
        className='flex items-center justify-between w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:w-auto dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:focus:text-white dark:border-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 md:dark:hover:bg-transparent'>
        ...
    </button>
    <div
        id='dropdownNavbar'
        className={`absolute top-[/navbar's height/] left-0 z-10 font-normal bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:divide-gray-600 ${isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}>
        <ul
            className='py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400'
            aria-labelledby='dropdownLargeButton'>
            <MenuDropDownItem title='Programming languages' path='#' />
            <MenuDropDownItem title='Repositories' path='#' />
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```